# window.open(...) with authorization

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

We have a GWT app that accesses REST API. REST API is meant for other uses too, and is secured using JAAS basic authorization. GWT app uses RestyGWT dispatcher and filter, as shown [here](http://ronanquillevere.github.io/2014/04/11/restygwt-basic-auth.html#.VEgNf_mUeYJ), to add *Authorization: Basic* to header, and, so far, this works fine.

However, our app also allows users to work with files, either download generated (such as pdf reports) or upload/download any kind files. We used servlets on server side for upload and download of these files, and `Window.open()` call to receive them in GWT. Without JAAS this worked fine.
Now I'm trying to secure that part of the API, too. `Window.open(...)` won't work because it doesn't allow for adding headers.

Is there some kind of workaround for this?

I've tried RequestBuilder, and I receive correct response, that contains the requested file. However, I'm not able to initiate the download of the file. Is it maybe possible to encode this (AJAX) response as [*data:...* URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and display it using, for example, iframe, which will, in turn, initiate file download?

Answer (score 1):

I always handled downloads by producing regular links. Wouldn't it be ok to check if a user session is valid and only then deliver the file?

By the way you could obtain an opened window's document and populate it:

```
public static native Document open(String url, String name, String features)/*-{
    return $wnd.open(url, name, features).document;
}-*/;
```

Comment: It is a requirement to secure both REST and servlets with JAAS basic. Therefore, I am not to use user session.